# Is it better to use Nested Master pages or User Controls for multi-sectioned website?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I am creating a website that has 5 different sub-sites each with the same overall look, but each has a different logo and added navigation.

What do you feel is a better approach:

- Use the new nested master page capabilities to create 5 sub-master pages.
- Use a single master page and dynamically load user controls corresponding to each sub-site's
  specific logo/navigation.

I'm currently going down the nested master page route.

**Update (12/19/2008):**

I am using Nested Master pages, and it is working out great. You are able to pass-through ContentPlaceHolders, and even have default content for the placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested Master is much better than loading a user control dynamically.  Dynamically loading a control is slow.

Answer (score 1):

A MasterPage is a control, which could also be loaded dynamically.  However, to answer your question, it sounds like different masterpages are the way to go.  It will give you much more flexibility, especially if say, one client wants their logo running down the side or something that a user control would not be able for.  Master will give you full control over wrapping html.

Comment: That makes even more reason to go with nested/different master pages to allow a greater degree of design change between sites.